# Cloud function URL doesn't work after deployment

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions, functions-framework

Note, this works perfectly when testing locally with Functions Framework.

I just deployed a function

```
Deploying function...
gcloud functions deploy quantumjs-api --runtime nodejs10 --trigger-http --project qunatumvue --region europe-west2
Deploying function (may take a while - up to 2 minutes)...done.
availableMemoryMb: 256
entryPoint: quantumjs-api
environmentVariables:
  location: production
httpsTrigger:
  url: https://europe-west2-qunatumvue.cloudfunctions.net/quantumjs-api
labels:
  deployment-tool: cli-gcloud
name: projects/qunatumvue/locations/europe-west2/functions/quantumjs-api
runtime: nodejs10
```

Edit  ---- thanks Doug Stevenson for the ping pointer

However, when posting data to it, I get no response back, just this error:

```
 "Error: Network Error
    at createError (webpack-internal:///./node_modules/axios/lib/core/createError.js:16:15)
    at XMLHttpRequest.handleError (webpack-internal:///./node_modules/axios/lib/adapters/xhr.js:87:14)"
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out my issue, I had to redirect all traffic to https has thats what my domain stared with in the cors policy file

Answer (score 0):

You can't ping a URL.  You ping a hostname.  The hostname in the URL you've given is "europe-west2-qunatumvue.cloudfunctions.net".  When I ping that, it's fine:

```
user@host 18:26 $ ping europe-west2-qunatumvue.cloudfunctions.net
PING www3.l.google.com (173.194.202.138) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from pf-in-f138.1e100.net (173.194.202.138): icmp_seq=1 ttl=42 time=29.3 ms
64 bytes from pf-in-f138.1e100.net (173.194.202.138): icmp_seq=2 ttl=42 time=29.3 ms
64 bytes from pf-in-f138.1e100.net (173.194.202.138): icmp_seq=3 ttl=42 time=29.3 ms
```

If you want to check if the URL works, you should instead access it with curl or some HTTP library.